# is it possible to paint diffuse and normal at the same time

Tags: texture-painting

I have a brick texture with diffuse and normal image. Is it possible to paint an object with stencil brush that while left clicking mouse, diffuse and normal can both be painted onto object's base color and normal image?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with bpaint.
But on personal recommendation, if you need that kind of thing, you better use of MASK factors. That way you connect and arm your shader first, then you only need to paint black and white map to reveal "layers".

Comment: Thank you for your replying. I watch some mask tutorials but I don't know how to achieve that in details. The point that confuses me is how to make object's two image (base color and normal) get painted at the same time coz for now I have to select only one of them to paint.

Comment: It is actually not possible to paint the details of a diffuse and a normal map at the same time - the normal information is something that uses special colors to show height, where the color information of the diffuse is totally a different thing. What Pierre describes here is using prematched images of both diffuse and normal and a stencil to reveal them together into the textures of the main material. This is not what you are looking for from the original question.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think I'm going to try substance painter. I was greedy about Blender doing everything. I guess that's not realistic.